# Java child class that can be refreshed with new instances of the parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, amazon-ec2

I'm working with the Java AWS API to monitor some EC2 instances and on every refresh I need to query the service which returns a bunch of `Instance` objects (freshly constructed). I want to extend the functionality of these objects, I figure I can maintain a map of  `MyInstance` objects which can be refreshed with the new `Instance`s on each poll.

Now I could easily do this with a simple wrapper class that holds the original `Instance` as a property the issue is I would like to keep access to the base `Instance` API as I already use these functions in my code. Would it be possible to replace only the super-class parts of an instantiated object? Contrived example of what I'm going for:

```
class Instance {
    protected int prop;

    public Instance(int prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}

class MyInstance extends Instance {
    protected int prop2;

    public MyInstance(int prop, int prop2) {
        super(prop);
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}

MyInstance foo = new MyInstance(1, 2);

Instance foster = new Instance(3);

//what i want to do
foo.adoptedBy(foster);
//with the result that foo.prop == 3
```

Obviously this example would be trivial to transform but in my actual case there are far more properties that need to be transferred. Can `Reflection` do this? What kind of performance impact am I looking at if I use `Reflection` for 10 of these every second? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to combine both your ideas:

1. Wrap the original Instance in a class that extends the Instance class. (In the constructor of the child class, you can create a new Instance object and set it)
2. Delegate all methods to the wrapped instance (and add new properties)
3. In your foster method, you simply change the wrapped Instance.

   ```
   class Instance {
     private int prop;

     public Instance(int prop) {
       this.prop = prop;
     }


     public int getProp() {
       return prop;
     }
   }

   class MyInstance extends Instance {
     private Instance delegate;
     private int prop2;

     public MyInstance(Instance delegate, int prop2) {
       super(prop);
       this.delegate = delegate;
       this.prop2 = prop2;
     }

     @Override
     public int getProp() {
       return delegate.getProp();
     }

     public int getProp2() {
       return prop2;
     }

     public void foster(Instance i) {
       delegate = i;
     }
   }

   MyInstance foo = new MyInstance(1, 2);

   Instance foster = new Instance(3);

   //what i want to do
   foo.adoptedBy(foster);
   //with the result that foo.getProp() == 3
   ```